# Statement has no effect 'AVPacket'

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am developing a Decoder using android NDK and FFmpeg native libraries. I have put Native Support for the project using Android Tools and I have the C code in videodecoder.cpp file. In the file the following function gives me this problem

```
JNIEXPORT jint Java_ssrp_android_ffmpegdecoder_H264Decoder_consumeNalUnitsFromDirectBuffer(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject nal_units, jint num_bytes,
        jlong pkt_pts) {
    DecoderContext *ctx = get_ctx(env, thiz);

    void *buf = NULL;
    if (nal_units == NULL) {
        D("Received null buffer, sending empty packet to decoder");
    } else {
        buf = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(nal_units);
        if (buf == NULL) {
            D("Error getting direct buffer address");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    AVPacket packet = {.data = (uint8_t*) buf, .size = num_bytes, .pts = pkt_pts };

    int frameFinished = 0;
    int res = avcodec_decode_video2(ctx->codec_ctx, ctx->src_frame,&frameFinished, &packet);

    if (frameFinished)
        ctx->frame_ready = 1;

    return res;
}
```

At the line `AVPacket packet = {.data = (uint8_t*) buf, .size = num_bytes, .pts = pkt_pts };`

It says that `Statement has no effect "AVPAcket" and

At the line `int res = avcodec_decode_video2(ctx->codec_ctx, ctx->src_frame,&frameFinished, &packet);`

It says that `Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
int avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *, AVFrame *, int *, const AVPacket *)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is

```
AVPacket packet = {.data = (uint8_t*) buf, .size = num_bytes, .pts = pkt_pts }
```

as the Compiler does not understand the type / initialization.
This leads to the invalid argument error.
Maybe split the line into:

```
AVPacket packet;
packet.data = (uint8_t*) buf;
packet.size = num_bytes;
packet.pts = pkt_pts;
```

This should get more clear error output.